# Removing Mysql doesn't Reset the Root Login

Tags: mysql

I have uninstalled the Mysql server using the below from my Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql*
```

During the installation, I entered the new root password from the prompt window.

After the installation, I am NOT able to login with the new root password, it works for the old one.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get the error after I enter the new password:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But it works fine when I enter the old password.

Also, when I log into Mysql with the old root password, I can see the table mysql.user still available as below. I need to remove the Mysql completely.

```
mysql>select host,user from mysql.user;
```

Why this happen? Is it a bug? How can I remove mysql and everything (including root logins, etc.) completely? Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: the commands you entered are for uninstalling, not installing

Comment: @RussellUhl: 
Yes. I want to uninstall it completely and then install it again. The installing commands are: apt-get install mysql-server. Please advise me how reset (remove everthing) and install again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer. I used also along with the commands above:

```
killall mysqld
killall mysqld_safe
```

And it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean it complete from your system, you should use `apt-get purge`, which is also removing modified configuration files etc. instead of just `apt-get remove`.

If your issue is only the root passwort you might not know anymore (I know you know yours in tis particular case), there are plenty of howtos on the web. e.g. [this one](http://www.device-leben.de/mysql-root-passwort-reset-ohne-downtime-debian-only/551/)

Comment: Shall I use: apt-get purge --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common instead of apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common ?

Comment: I tried apt-get purge --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common and it didn't work, still unable to login with the new root password and able to login with the old password